# Bash function printing certain lines blue

Tags: bash, colors

Am having difficulty understanding the following function.  It is supposed to colour
lines starting with `-` or with `{-` using `blue`.  How are not matching lines still printed?

```
kls ()
 {
  rst='tput sgr0'
  ctp='tput bold; tput setaf 39'
  sed -E "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}; printf '%s' '&';${rst}/e" <<< "$@"
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to _delete nonmatching lines_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two variables `rst` and `ctp` in your code contain shell commands.  It would be better if you simply made them contain the output of those command as it allows us to drop the unsafe `/e` option to the substitution command in your GNU `sed` invocation.

```bash
kls () {
    local ctp="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"
    local rst="$( tput sgr0 )"
    sed -E "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}&${rst}/" <<< "$@"
}
```

The question seems to ask how to *avoid* printing nonmatching lines.  You do this, in this case, by using the `-n` option with `sed`, which disables the default output of each line at the end of the editing script. You then add the `/p` option to the substitution command, which will cause the line modified by the substitution to be outputted (lines not matching the regular expression will not be outputted).

```bash
kls () {
    local ctp="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"
    local rst="$( tput sgr0 )"
    sed -E -n "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}&${rst}/p" <<< "$@"
}
```

To make this a bit more like a filter, drop the redirect into `sed`:

```bash
kls () {
    local ctp="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"
    local rst="$( tput sgr0 )"
    sed -E -n "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}&${rst}/p"
}
```

You would use this with

```bash
printf '%s\n' "some" "strings" | kls
```

or

```bash
kls <some-file
```

or

```bash
some-general-command | kls
```

Comment: Why would the `printf` be unnecessary?